# extglob behavior, particularly when using *(patternList) in bash

Tags: bash, command-line, wildcards

I am trying to use extglob, however, after the man pages I'm confused about how *(patternList) operates. 
Assume I use the following commands:

```
touch A  Ax  Axxx  Axxxx  Ay  X  X.bak  x  xx  xxxx 
ls A*(xx)
```

Why does this only print A  Axxxx. Doesn't Axxx also contain exactly one occurrence of xx? Furthermore, why is Ay not printed since it has 0 occurences of xx?

Answer (score 3):

The pattern must be a match for the whole name, not just a prefix of the name.

`Ay` does not match `A*(xx)` because it does not consist of `A` followed by any number of `xx`. The `y` is not matched by the pattern. `Ay` does match `A*(xx)y` and `A*(xx)?` and `A*(xx)*`.

Similarly, `Axxx` does not match `A*(xx)` because it does not consist of `A` followed by any number of `xx`. `Axxx` does match `A*(x)` (`A` followed by three times `x`), `A*(xx)x` (`A` followed by one time `xx` followed by `x`), `A*(xx)?`, `A*(xx)*`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> Doesn't Axxx also contain exactly one occurrence of xx?

It does - but it also has an additional `x` that is not matched by the pattern `A*(xx)`. It would be matched by `A*(xx)?` for example.

> Furthermore, why is Ay not printed since it has 0 occurences of xx?

Again, because there is nothing in the pattern to match the trailing `y`.

I guess what it comes down to is that globs are *whole string* matches.